# Make Postgresql Fulltext Search return full document with highlighted results

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Postgresql's Fulltext-Serach is great. I use it like this:

```
SELECT 
  ts_headline('german', translation, query, 'MaxWords=999') as highlighted 
FROM 
  <tblname>,
  plainto_tsquery('<searchword>') as query
WHERE 
  to_tsvector('german', translation) @@ query)
```

(The real query is more complicate and contains some joins, but that has nothing to do with my problem.)

Even with MaxWords=999 the returned *highlighted* is a cropped version of *translation*, not starting at the beginning of *translation*, but where the first occurrence of *searchword*.

How is it possible to get the full document, *translation* in this example, with highlighted hits?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `ts_headline('german', translation, query, 'HighlightAll=TRUE')`

Comment: Thank you, I obviously oversaw this option reading the manual somehow!